# ufw cancel port forward

Tags: ubuntu, ufw

On Ubuntu server 14.04, I enabled ufw port forwarding from 80 to 8181 (tcp) by using the checked answer on [Can I use ufw to setup a port forward?](https://serverfault.com/questions/238563/can-i-use-ufw-to-setup-a-port-forward)

Finally I'd rather proxy http request using apache2 proxy capabilities.
So I removed the added lines to /etc/ufw/before.rules, then disabled/reenabled ufw.

And the port forwarding is still active. Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

A simple reboot is enough. My guess is that it cleared iptables. So my question is now : how could I have this done without rebooting ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By flushing the chains in the NAT table and removing any sub-chains:

```
ufw disable
iptables  --table nat  --flush
iptables  --table nat  --delete-chain
ufw enable
```

Short options: `--table|-t`,  `--delete-chain|-X`

Comment: This did not work for me, I had same problem.  After doing the above and robooting things started working for me, not sure if it was a combo of the two or if a reboot alone would have fixed.  BTW ubuntu 22.04, same problem.