# Linux FTP server which can work with unsalted SHA256 hashes?

Tags: ftp, password, vsftpd, hash

## Problem

Some old [WS_FTP server](https://www.ipswitch.com/ftp-client) stopped booting at work after a Windows update. The corresponding admin is long gone. The only information I have is :

- file structure
- user names
- unsalted SHA256 hash for each user

One of those hashes is:

> 5e884898da28047151d0e56f8dc6292773603d0d6aabbdd62a11ef721d1542d8

which corresponds to `"password"`. I could check with : `echo -n password | sha256sum`.

I don't even know where the FTP clients are. Some of them are remote sensors to which I cannot get access. They were still sending data until the server stopped. The data isn't confidential but important to us nonetheless.

## Attempts

- I tried running [john the ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) on the hashes. It found 4 passwords out of 30.
- I tried to find a Linux FTP server which uses unsalted SHA256 hashes. I think it's too insecure so no server proposed it, at least not as default
- Some servers (e.g. [vsftpd](https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd.html)) delegate to htpasswd. I couldn't find a way to save an unsalted SHA256 hash, though.

## Question

Is it possible to create a `htpasswd` hash with SHA256, without salt and only one round? The minimum seems to be a 8-byte salt and 1000 rounds with `mkpasswd`.

Is there another linux FTP server which can be configured to work with thoses hashes?

I don't care much about security, I'd just like to set-up an FTP server which accepts incoming connections from the sensors.

Comment: You might simply install a replacement FTP server, set up the accounts with the passwords you do know  and use a network sniffer to collect the (failing) passwords of the accounts that you are missing.

Comment: @HBruijn: That could work, yes. Thanks for the comment. Do you know any "fake" FTP-server which simply dumps the failed passwords?

Comment: @EricDuminil Simply use a laptop with the same IP and wireshark. For FTP you could use pyftpdlib: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyftpdlib/

Comment: @Broco: pyftpdlib might be just what I need, thanks. I'll try it and comment back.

Comment: @Broco: It worked perfectly. See [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/903533/linux-ftp-server-which-can-work-with-unsalted-sha256-hashes/905974#905974). Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Broco suggested to use [pyftpdlib](https://github.com/giampaolo/pyftpdlib), which worked perfectly for my needs!

Here are the steps:

- Install a Linux server
- Install [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/)
- Install [pyftpdlib](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyftpdlib)
- Create a json file with a dict of username, hash and folder
- Create a pyftpdlib script for an FTP server which compares the SHA256 hashes
- [Redirect](https://serverfault.com/a/238565/442344) port 21 to port 8021
- Run it as a [systemd unit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30189540/6419007) as a non-privileged user
- Restart the [ftp server automatically](https://superuser.com/questions/1171751/restart-systemd-service-automatically-whenever-a-directory-changes-any-file-ins) if the json file is modified.

Here's a template for the json file:

```
{
    "user1": {
        "folder": "users/user1",
        "sha256": "DFB0CE07EDF923F1F40BA56CC9BA9C396B53E3399E3164D60E35050BAA2BE9C9"
    },
    "user2": {
        "folder": "users/user2",
        "sha256": "5E884898DA28047151D0E56F8DC6292773603D0D6AABBDD62A11EF721D1542D8"
    }
}
```

Here's the script:

```
#!/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -u
#encoding: UTF-8
import re
import os
import hashlib
import json
from pathlib import Path
from pyftpdlib.authorizers import DummyAuthorizer, AuthenticationFailed
from pyftpdlib.handlers import FTPHandler
from pyftpdlib.servers import FTPServer
from pyftpdlib.filesystems import AbstractedFS

FTP_FOLDER = Path("/media/ftp_data")

with open('input/ftp_users.json') as users_json:
    USERS = json.loads(users_json.read())

current_folder = Path.cwd().resolve()


def login_dump(username, password, success):
    if success:
        subfolder = 'logins'
        attr = 'w'
    else:
        subfolder = 'logins/failed'
        attr = 'a'
    logins_folder = current_folder.joinpath(subfolder)
    logins_folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    with open(str(logins_folder.joinpath(username)), attr) as user_file:
        # NOTE: Could write better hash directly, e.g. with `mkpasswd -m sha-512`
        user_file.write(password + "\n")


class SHA256Authorizer(DummyAuthorizer):
    def validate_authentication(self, username, password, handler):
        sha256_hash = hashlib.sha256(password.encode('ascii')).hexdigest().upper()
        try:
            # NOTE: Case sensitive!
            if self.user_table[username]['pwd'] != sha256_hash:
                login_dump(username, password, False)
                raise AuthenticationFailed
        except KeyError:
            login_dump(username, password, False)
            raise AuthenticationFailed
        login_dump(username, password, True)


authorizer = SHA256Authorizer()

for user, params in USERS.items():
    print("Adding user %r" % user)
    folder = FTP_FOLDER.joinpath(params['folder'])
    folder.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    authorizer.add_user(user,
                        params['sha256'].upper(),
                        str(folder),
                        perm="elradfmw",
                        msg_login="Welcome, %s!" % user)
handler = FTPHandler
handler.authorizer = authorizer
handler.banner = "FTP server"


class WindowsOrUnixPathFS(AbstractedFS):
    def ftpnorm(self, ftppath):
        # NOTE: Some old clients still think they talk to a Windows Server
        return super().ftpnorm(ftppath.replace("\\", "/"))


handler.abstracted_fs = WindowsOrUnixPathFS

handler.passive_ports = range(40000, 40500)
# NOTE: Port forwarding is needed because this script shouldn't be run as root.
# See https://serverfault.com/a/238565/442344
server = FTPServer((IP_ADDRESS, 8021), handler)
server.serve_forever()
```

The script logs the passwords in plain text, which is acceptable because the data isn't confidential. After a few months, I'll switch to vsftpd.