# Conditional port forwarding with ufw as a default policy

Tags: ubuntu, security, iptables, firewall, ufw

Is there a way such that: when a connection is denied (by the rule set) in `ufw`, it forwards that traffic to another port on the local machine, rather than dropping (by default)?

I can see two potential ways for port forwarding in `ufw`, I am wondering how to modify these so that it is conditional.

1. Adding `-A PREROUTING` rule to `/etc/ufw/before.rules`. But I need that rule only to be applied when the connection should not be allowed (as defined in the `ufw` rules). In other words, as the default rule (to forward instead of block).
2. `sudo ufw route`, but how to apply that route only for denied connections? [The example I see](https://serverfault.com/a/1016101/763876) does not have a condition set. (set that as a catch-all default policy). **Is it possible to add route as the default rule for connections?**

Comment: In that case you are not dropping the traffic at all! You are just port forwarding.

Comment: @MichaelHampton That's right. I have updated the title and content accordingly. Thanks!